# Django testing a simple model with Foreign Key and UpdateView

Tags: django, testing

Two very simple models

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='location_number', db_column='location_number', related_name='projects', verbose_name='Standort')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

with an UpdateView

```
from .models import Project
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = "__all__"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'project_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

should be tested with this simple test:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Project, Location
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from django.utils.http import urlencode

class ProjectUpdateTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.location = Location.objects.create(
            name='Test Location',
        )
        
        self.project = Project.objects.create(
            location=self.location,
            slug="test",
            name='Test Project',
        )

    def test_project_update_view(self):
        # Prepare the data for the form
        form_data = {
            'name': 'Updated Project',
            'location': self.location.pk,
            'slug': 'test',
        }

        # Build the URL for the project detail view
        url = reverse('update_project', kwargs={
            'project_slug': self.project.slug
        })

        # Encode the form data as form-encoded data
        encoded_form_data = urlencode(form_data, doseq=True)

        # Send a POST request to the project update view with the form-encoded data
        response = self.client.post(url, data=encoded_form_data, content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

        # Print form errors, if any
        form = response.context['form']
        print(form.errors)

        self.project.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(self.project.name, 'Updated Project')
```

But it fails with

> location
>
> Select a
> valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
> choices.
>
> F
> ====================================================================== FAIL: test_project_update_view
> (playground.tests.ProjectUpdateTest.test_project_update_view)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/code/playground/tests.py",
> line 43, in test_project_update_view
>     self.assertEqual(self.project.name, 'Updated Project') AssertionError: 'Test Project' != 'Updated Project'
> - Test Project
> + Updated Project

What ever I try

- 'location': self.location.pk
- 'location': self.location,
- 'location': self.location.id,

the form does not accept the location as a valid choice

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

Can somebody help with what I oversee? – Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `to_field` is `to_field='location_number'`, so you pass the name of the `location` with:

```
form_data = {
    'name': 'Updated Project',
    'location': self.location.location_number,
    'slug': 'test',
}
```

here this will thus likely be the empty string.

Comment: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem helping me to not going crazy ;)) Unfortunately using 'location': self.location.location_number, ends in the form error:   <ul class="errorlist"><li>location<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: @toni: what if you create the location with a `location_number'` filled in a non-empty string. Looks like this might be a problematic case the Django forms module has not considered.

Comment: @toni: if it works with a non-empty string, I will submit a ticket regarding this. But the likely response is that this is just something that is how a HTML form works.

Comment: you are genius. Thanks a million. This made me crazy the whole day! I can confirm it is working when I setup the location obj with location_number yeahhhh!

Comment: And maybe also good to know it is only working if I set location_number='1', which is the pk of the created test location

Comment: @toni: what if you set `location_number='a'` and then `'a'` in the from post, so `'location': 'a'`?

Comment: 'a' does it as well like https://hastebin.com/share/koyufucane.ruby but what I do not find logical here is that when I create the project in setup  self.project = Project.objects.create( I have to use self.location and not 'a'. Does this make sense? (So this will not work ... https://hastebin.com/share/megukafale.ruby)

Comment: @toni: it works with `Project.objects.create(location_id='a', ...)`

Comment: Oh yes, so the use of location_number is causing my confusion. Lesson learned!